# Microsoft Azure Computer Vision OCR Adds NewLine when Tab Encountered

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

The OCR response seems to return any space larger than a standard space as a new line.
Wondering if there's some kind of configuration or editing that may be possible to client to influence this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mentioning to set the line-end-up signal to more than 2 or 3 "spaces". Currently this is not supported.

The only related skill I have seen is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-ocr#skill-parameters

But for the Read API itself, I don't think this is doable. I will forward this idea to product group.